# Char to int with a value more than 9

Tags: string, char, type-conversion, ascii

I have a string data that is used to load certain levels, and upon completing the level, some piece of code should increase the last char of the string to properly load the next level.

For example:

```
String levelName = "Level_002_001";
```

After completing the level, it should create a string = "Level_002_002", which works with the code below until "Level_002_009", and upon loading the 10th level, it trows an error.

Code:

```
string sceneName = Application.loadedLevelName;
char[] chars = sceneName.ToCharArray();
int level = chars[chars.Length - 1] - '0';
ManageLevelData.SaveLevel(level, ScoreController.Percentage());
chars[chars.Length - 1] = (char)(((int)'0')+ level + 1);
Application.LoadLevel(new string(chars));
```

In human language: I seperate each character of the string in an array, then take the last char and convert it to an int, then increase it with 1, and glue it all back together.

Comment: Maybe `chars[chars.Length - 1]++` instead?  Maybe `ManageLevelData.SaveLevel()` does not like 10 or `Application.LoadLevel("Level_002_00:")` is bad?

Comment: I think your answer will add one int to the ascii char, and since the ascii char only goes to 9, I'll have to add another char probably... And no, both functions just read a string, and as far as I know, the parsing method is legit, but thanks for answering :)

Comment: It appears you want increment "..._009" and go to "..._010" and not "..._00:".  Code needs to deal with _textual_ math overflow eventually either when it is incrementing "..._009", "..._999" or "Level_999_999".  I suggest parse _all_ the digits that may participate in `level`, increment `level`, and then re-from the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

```
   char[] chars = sceneName.ToCharArray();
   int level = chars[chars.Length - 1] - '0';
   if(level >= 9)
   {
       int previousChar = chars[chars.Length - 2] - '0';
       previousChar++;
       chars[chars.Length - 2] = (char)(((int)'0') + previousChar);
       chars[chars.Length - 1] = '0';
       Debug.Log(new string(chars));
   }
   else
      chars[chars.Length - 1] = (char)(((int)'0') + level + 1);
```

Did the trick, only works until 99 if I'm not wrong, I really hoped there was a function for this. :O